# How do I get the total for tqdm to be equal to the length of the value of two zip variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now the main for loop tqdm bar always shows a total out of 7. I the user input was for all 7 days of the week then that would be fine. Problem is if the user input only 3 days or any other value other then 7 it still shows total of 7. How do I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

print("""
+---------+----------------------+
| Days    | Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su |
| On  = 1 |  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 |
| Off = 0 |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 |
+---------+----------------------+
""")

day_input = (int(val) for val in input("Enter days : ").split())
days = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')

print()

for val, day in tqdm(zip(day_input, days), position=2, colour='green', total=len(days)):
    if not val:
        continue
    first = np.busday_offset(np.datetime64('2022-01-01'), 0, roll='forward', weekmask=day)
    last = np.busday_offset(np.datetime64('1002022-01-01'), 1, roll='preceding', weekmask=day)
    delta = np.timedelta64(7, 'D')
    arange = np.arange(first, last, delta)
    array = np.array(arange)

    for a in tqdm(array, position=0, leave=False, desc=day, colour='blue'):
        pass
```

Comment: change your total parameter in tqdm to `total=len(day_input)` as right now your expected total is always len(days) = 7

Comment: I tried that. Get TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: you can convert to a list first `total=len(list(day_input))`. Outside of this example, if your iterator is very large then you can do something more memory friendly `total=sum(1 for x in generator_obj)`

Comment: Tried both those options too. I dont get an error but it halts at the for loop. never runs after the inputs are taken. lol dont know what else to try

Comment: you can convert `day_input` outside of the for loop to a list: `day_input = list(int(val) for val in input("Enter days : ").split())`

Comment: Still shows 7/7 because it is counting the zeroes. If user inputs, 1  0  1  0  1  0  0 for mon wed fri it should result in len of 3 but its counting the zeroes so output is 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change:

```py
day_input = (int(val) for val in input("Enter days : ").split())
days = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')

print()

for val, day in tqdm(zip(day_input, days), position=2, colour='green', total=len(days)):
    if not val:
        continue
    first = np.busday_offset(np.datetime64('2022-01-01'), 0, roll='forward', weekmask=day)
...
```

into:

```py
days = ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
input_days = [x[0] for x in filter(lambda d: d[1] != 0, zip(days, (int(val) for val in input("Enter days : ").split())))]

for day in tqdm(input_days, position=2, colour='green'):
    first = np.busday_offset(np.datetime64('2022-01-01'), 0, roll='forward', weekmask=day)
...
```

The main idea is to filter days based on the user's input and then pass the list with only the selected days to `tqdm`.

Comment: didn't work. When i inputted '1 0 1 0 1 0 0' for 'mon wed fri' it did show the correct total of 3 but, the progress bar went from 33% to 100% before it finished with friday. So it is still factoring the zeroes.

Comment: Dude your a beast lol good stuff. It's faster to now too. Just started learning programming only been a month lol. Thank you.

Comment: It's nothing! Glad to help :)